# Packaging operation failed

Tags: ios, xcode4, app-store, package

Im trying to update my app on appstore, and keep getting the "Packaging operation failed"
Im pretty sure that the name, bundle identifier, relase provisioning,version name etc. is the same as the old app, already checked many posts here and the web but doesnt work as well....
Any sugestions please?
working on Xcode 4.3

EDIT:
I think theres something wrong, when i archieve i see in the organizer :"Estimated app store size: 7 kb" 7 kb?

EDIT 2 :

I was using the library ShareKIT for integration with social networks, facebook, delicious etc., Usually worked with IOS Simulator, or on my own device. The accused does not log anything wrong, but after much trial and error, delete the library and tried again, i worked normally. Here was the solution I found.

Comment: Your question makes it difficult to help you. Did you look into the logs under the Log navigator? Did you expand the failure message? What does it say (edit your question to include it)?

Comment: I have the same problem and don't know where to access any of the log information. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

To see "log information", in Xcode, use View->Navigators->Show-Log-Navigator